# Как создать свое собственное облачное хранилище?

Tags: облако, сервер, облачное-хранилище

Хочу создать свое собственное облако. Как я могу этого добиться? Кто понимает и знает, опишите мне пожалуйста как можно добиться такого? Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот, почитай, очень хорошая статейка. [**Клик**](http://habrahabr.ru/post/154047/)

Comment: спасибо! Сегодня вы мне очень помогли!))

Comment: @navi1893, я рад, что кто-то ценит мой труд. Чем смогу, тем буду помогать)

Comment: @navi1893, Только, на галочку возле вопроса нажмите, для полного счастья))

Comment: уже сделано!))